# How to change the font size of a pie chart's legend

Tags: plotting, fonts

I have a pie chart and I would like to make the font size of the legend bigger.

I was able to make the fonts bigger for the chart labels but `BaseStyle->{FontSize -> 15}` did not work for the legend.

How could I do it?

My pie chart's code:

```
PieChart[{number1, number2, number3, number4}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Fraudster Login Frequency", 
  ChartLegends -> {"only once", "2-9 times", "10-199 times", ">200 times"}, 
  ChartLabels -> {"6%", "17%", "63%", "14%"}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
number1 = .06;
number2 = .17;
number3 = .63;
number4 = .14;
PieChart[{number1, number2, number3, number4}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Fraudster Login Frequency", 
 ChartLegends -> {Text[Style["only once", 15]], 
   Text[Style["2--9 times", 15]], Text[Style["10--199 times", 15]], 
   Text[Style["> 200 times", 15]]}, 
 ChartLabels -> {"6%", "17%", "63%", "14%"}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

and if you want to make multiple such pie charts, this will allow you to change merely the `numbers`:

```
numbers = {.06, .17, .63, .14};
PieChart[numbers,
 PlotLabel -> "Fraudster Login Frequency", 
 ChartLegends -> (Style[#, 15] & /@ {"only once", "2-9 times", 
     "10-199 times", ">200 times"}),
 ChartLabels -> (StringJoin[ToString[#], "%"] & /@ 
    IntegerPart[100 numbers]),
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel"]
```

Comment: Or more simply, `ChartLegends -> (Style[#, 15] & /@ {"only once", "2-9 times", "10-199 times", ">200 times"})`

Comment: Perfect! thanks!!